# Enable deferred scrolling only on vertical scrollBar

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

Is it possible to only set deferred scrolling on one scrollBar (vertical in my example) and not on whole scrollViewer control?

Comment: looks like you have some way to defer the scrolling on both horizontal and vertical scrollbars?

Comment: @KingKing Setting ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled=“True” on DataGrid does just that, but deferred scrolling is enabled for both vertical and horizontal scrollbar.